# Unity C# (Mono) enum fault

Tags: c#, enums, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm defining this code:

```
public enum ModelType {
    R4,
    W6,
    W8,
    W9,
    X9
}
```

and I'm using this function in another script:

```
public void RequestModel(ModelType type, Size size) {
    Debug.Log("Requesting " + type.ToString() + " at size " + size.ToString());
}
```

the output result is:

```
Requesting 9 at size 4
```

If I change the code in

```
Debug.Log("Requesting " + (int)type + " at size " + size.ToString());
```

I'll get the same result.
Does someone know what's going on?

I have to say that the first time I wrote the enum it was like:

```
public enum ModelType {
    EX1,
    EX2,
    EX3,
    EX4,
    EX5,
    EX6,
    EX7,
    R4,
    W6,
    W8,
    W9,
    X9
}
```

but I got rid of the EXes because I don't need them anymore.

I also tried to add again the EXes and I got the outputs:

```
Requesting W8 at size 4  // if I use ToString()
Requesting 9 at size 4   // to print the enum value
```

that are ok.

I really don't know what to do.
I tried to reimport all, restart Unity and Visual Studio but if I delete the EXes nothing will work properly.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
sorry guy, I forgot to mention that in the code I'm calling the function as

```
RequestModel(ModelType.W8, Size._4);
```

having the wierd result already described.

Comment: What exactly is your error?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what you think your problem is.

Comment: the problem is that as the enum is defined like that if I use the function like this: 'RequestModel(ModelType.W8, Size._4)' instead of returning the correct values I got this 9 as mentioned into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the "EX" options in place, `W8` will map to a value of 9.  When you removed them, it now maps to 2.  If you're loading `ModelType type` from something that had the value serialized as 9, it would explain the difference - `type` would actually be 9, which no longer exists in your enum, so `ToString` will print the numeric value.

I recommend fixing your enum to specify the values explicitly, as this will make it backwards compatible.

```
public enum ModelType 
{
    R4 = 7,
    W6 = 8,
    W8 = 9,
    W9 = 10,
    X9 = 11
}
```

Comment: Well, this will solve the issue. Thanks. I'm still trying to understand the reason of this behaviour and why it will not be fixed simply by changing the enum. Deleting the EXes values will require to change all the code that previously used them (like switch or if) and I've never used the int value of the enum in my code. Strange...

Comment: @Apache81 If you saved the value and loaded it, it could explain why you've had this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: in an initialisation method there was a declared BUT NOT INITIALIZED variable:

```
ModelType currentModel;
```

I don't know for what reason but that variable just got the strange value of 9 (corresponding to the old value of the W8 enum) and the initialization method was parsed before the function call described in the question.

I solved the issue by initializing the variable.

Thanks to everyone guys !!!   :)